# Determine which app store my application was downloaded from?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to determine the specific country app store my application was downloaded from?  I would like to distinguish if a user downloaded my application from the us app store vs. the canada app store?

Not interested in locale settings but the actual store the app came from.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112046/detect-at-runtime-which-countrys-app-store-my-iphone-app-was-downloaded-from

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because I don't think it matters on device.

- iTunes Connect tells you when a user "upgrades", but I think this is per iTunes account, not per device. Presumably the iTunes Store keeps track of this.
- The device keeps track of which account an app is from (it prompts you for the correct account password if you have apps from multiple accounts).
- The device keeps track of a store country (so it knows which one to connect to).
- I don't think it keeps track of the store that an account is on (you can be logged in with a US account but be connected to the UK store).

The closest is the current iTunes store country (which might have changed since the user installed the app, or the app could've been installed by syncing with iTunes), but I don't think this is in an accessible file.

Comment: if the device keeps track of a store country to connect to, do you know how to access that?

Comment: @lothard There's no official way to do that. Maybe there's one for jailbroken devices, but you'd have to ask somebody who has more experience with that stuff.