# iOS - Knowing app store country

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I want to know in my app (by code) in which app store my user is (like england / france / spain ect).

I already read that we can do this with the locale :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643060-countrycode

But I would like to do it with the Apple Store. For legal purpose I don't want to display the same content for an european than for an american.

Has someone already done it ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112046/detect-at-runtime-which-countrys-app-store-my-iphone-app-was-downloaded-from

Comment: @Maximelc None of the answers to that linked question actually answer that (or this) question.

Comment: If your app happens to make use of in-app purchases, there is a possible solution.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot get any information about the signed in user. In my personal apps I have made I also display content for the users iTunes Store. My solution was on first launch get their current locale, and save which store they should be using. I allow the user to change this setting in the app though because I could be wrong.

Comment: Ask the user at signup which store they use.

Comment: Unfortunatly my app does not use in-app purchase. How could this help me ?

Comment: @rmaddy how we cna get appstore country If we are using inApp? as my application is using inAPP purchase

Comment: @MoazSaeed I believe I was thinking of the `priceLocale` from `SKProduct` but this probably isn't really a 100% correct solution.

Answer (score 20):

From iOS13 `SKStorefront` class property `countryCode` can be used to get three-letter code representing the country associated with the App Store storefront.

For iOS version below 13 only viable solution was to get `priceLocale` from `SKProduct`.

Comment: Can I use it even if I don't have In-App purchase in my app?

Comment: Not checked but I think that you just need to import StoreKit. This class doesn't depends on any purchases.

Comment: SKStorefront.countryCode is always USA for me. My device belongs to the Swedish App Store. Sandbox issue or is this not working properly?

Comment: @RobertGummesson Did you run it on the Simulator?

Answer (score 13):

If you're on iOS 13+, This will give you the 3 letter country code for the store:

```
import StoreKit

let country = SKPaymentQueue.default().storefront?.countryCode
```

More information on it's usage can be found in the [SKStoreFront documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront).

UPDATE:
Occasionally, this method returns nil, which is why storefront is an optional. So it's not 100% reliable. I was using with thousands of users, and it was working 95% of the time. I'm not entirely sure under what circumstances it is nil however.

Comment: Does not work. The result is always nil.  Tested with iPod touch 7th Generation 14.4 and iPhone 11 :(

Comment: I was using with thousands of users, and it was working 95% of the time. But you're right, sometimes it does return nil. I'm not sure why, nor have I investigated why. It could be due to restrictions or maybe not being logged into the app store. No idea.

Answer (score 8):

You can't restrict IAP(so you don't have information about the Apple Store used) for specific country. 
What you can do is disable/enable items by checking country ID.

there are different way for check it, for me the best is by checking user carrier ID.

For example:

```
func checkCellularNumber() -> Bool {
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    guard let info = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider else {return false}
    if let carrier = info.isoCountryCode {
        print("Carrier code = \(carrier)");
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: If it's WiFi only device, I don't believe this will work.